# Slim algorithm with unique result for combining two numbers

Tags: javascript, math, hash

I have a vector class with two double components and precision up to the third decimal place which is instantiated like a billion times per second.
I calculate their length about as many times.
Now I want to store the lengths in memory and I thought something like a HashMap/dictionary would be a good idea but that means that I need a key. So I thought: Why not use the vector components. Since I can't have two keys I'm looking for a way to throw these two numbers together (order obviously doesn't matter) and get a unique result.

A buddy of mine proposed using MD5 but I thought it might be overkill (I never thought that I would say that about MD5).

Comment: What type is the numbers in the vector?

Comment: "to throw these two numbers together" So it's two-dimensional vectors?

Answer (score 2):

simply concatenate the two values? so use a 128bit key, the first 64bits are the first double, the second 64bit the second double?

Depending on the language you're using, you'll be able to use an Object/Struct/whatever as key, too.

You memory usage will be enormous, though.

Answer (score 2):

As you say, md5 feels quite overkill. There are lots of simple hash-functions, for example the XOR hash is common for low level stuff

```
unsigned xor_hash ( void *key, int len )
{
    unsigned char *p = key;
    unsigned h = 0;
    int i;

    for ( i = 0; i < len; i++ )
        h ^= p[i];

    return h;
}
```

But if performance is important, you should search for a checksum that performs well for your kind of data. There is no golden answer.

There are many alternatives [here](http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/algorithms/jsw_tut_hashing.aspx), all of them quite easy to implement and test. You can also experiment with the length of the checksum to see how longer checksums impacts other parts of the application (performance-wise).

Answer (score 1):

A bit 'brute force' but how about concatenating the string representations? If you force your numbers to 3 decimal places, 12.23 and 100.1 would be 12.230100.100

The only drawback is that converting to string takes a lot of time - I think more than DThoughts' suggestion of concatenation the double values. You could test that.